# Maui Shell Login MVVM issue on Logout

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm, maui

I am new to Maui, xaml and Mvvm. I am trying to create a Maui Shell app but when I logout and  await gotoasync the page does not recreate and has the data from the first login still. Any input would be very helpful! i have tried to add Transient and Add Singleton, I have Tried Different Binding Contexts.

**Login View**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CpdiMobileApp.TabletViews.TabletLogin"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2022/xaml/maui"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CpdiMobileApp"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" 
    Title="TabletLogin"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" 
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
  
 
  <StackLayout Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  >

 <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
            
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="cpdi.png"  HeightRequest="75" MaximumWidthRequest="200" />
                <Label FontSize="25" HorizontalOptions="Center"   FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{local:Translate LoginHeader}" />
            </StackLayout>
     
            <Label TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Failmessage}" x:Name="ErrorMessage"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
     
            <!--UserName-->
            <Border  StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15,15,15"    StrokeThickness="5" >
                <telerik:RadEntry Placeholder="{local:Translate UsernamePlaceholder}"  
                   ValidationErrorMessage="{local:Translate UsernamePlaceholderError}"
                   IsValueValid="{Binding Validusername}"
                   Text="{Binding Username}"               
                   TextColor="#000" 
                   TextChanged="txtUserName_TextChanged"
                   FontSize="Medium"
                   x:Name="txtUserName"
                   BorderBrush ="Transparent"
                   PlaceholderColor="#154360"
                   BackgroundColor="White"   
                   />
            </Border>
     
            <!--Password-->
            <Border  StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15,15,15"    StrokeThickness="5" >
                <telerik:RadEntry IsPassword="True" 
                   ValidationErrorMessage="{local:Translate PasswordPlaceholderError}"
                   BorderBrush ="Transparent"
                   TextColor="#000" 
                   FontSize="Medium"
                   IsValueValid="{Binding Validpassword}"
                   Text="{Binding Password}" 
                   x:Name="txtPassword"
                    TextChanged="txtPassword_TextChanged"
                   Placeholder="{local:Translate PasswordPlaceholder}"  
                   BackgroundColor="White"  
                   PlaceholderColor="#154360"/>
            </Border>

            <!--LoginButton-->
            <telerik:RadButton VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{local:Translate LoginButton}" 
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                    BackgroundColor="#257CB8"
                     BorderColor="#919191"
                    BorderWidth="1.5"
                    CornerRadius="15"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    />

            <!--BarcodeButton-->
            <telerik:RadButton  VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{local:Translate BarcodeButton}" 
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    TextColor="#257CB8"   
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    BorderColor="#257CB8"
                    BorderWidth="1.5"
                    CornerRadius="15"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    Clicked="BarcodeSignIn_Clicked"
                    />

           <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                <!--English-->
                <Border  StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,0,15,0" Background="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stroke="#257CB8" >
                   <telerik:RadButton  VerticalOptions="Center" Text="English" 
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    TextColor="#257CB8"   
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                     Clicked="English_Clicked"
                    />
                </Border>
                <!--Espanol-->
                <Border  StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 0,15,0,15" Background="#257CB8" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stroke="#919191" >
                   <telerik:RadButton VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Español" 
                    BackgroundColor="#257CB8"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                     Clicked="Espanol_Clicked"
                    />
                </Border>
                
            </HorizontalStackLayout>

        </StackLayout>


    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Shell**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="CpdiMobileApp.TabletAppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CpdiMobileApp.TabletViews"
    >

    <ShellItem Route="TabletLogin" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TabletLogin}"/>
    </ShellItem>


    <FlyoutItem Title="Home">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TabletHomePage}" Route="TabletHomePage"/>

    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Settings">
        <ShellContent Title="Settings" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TabletSettings}" Route="TabletSettings"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Sign Out" Clicked="SignOut_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    </Shell>
```

**View Model Base**

```cs
namespace CpdiMobileApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _isBusy;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _title;
    }
}
```

**App cs**

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new TabletAppShell();     
}
```

**AppShell cs**

```cs
public partial class TabletAppShell : Shell
{
    public TabletAppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TabletHomePage), typeof(TabletHomePage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TabletSettings), typeof(TabletSettings));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TabletLogin), typeof(TabletLogin));
    }

    private async void SignOut_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        Preferences.Clear("refresh-token");
        Preferences.Clear("refresh-token-expires");
        Preferences.Clear("token");
        Preferences.Clear("userid");
        Preferences.Clear("username");
    
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(TabletLogin)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: you have not posted any code for Login or Logout

Comment: Please show all **relevant** code, only showing some XAML isn't helpful. How are your *AppShell.xaml.cs* and *App.xaml.cs* set up? How are your routes defined? You seem to be using Shell's dependency injection, so please show those things as they are relevant.

Comment: Sorry it was giving me the most of your post is code remarks when posting.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Please update (and properly format) your question. Remember to only include code that is relevant.

Comment: Updated Posted - add  AppShell.xaml.cs and add App.xaml.cs

Comment: @ScottNoClue Please improve the formatting. Make sure not to include non-code text between the triple backticks and create one code block per code file/class depending on what you're showing. At the moment you have one huge code block with poor formatting which is very difficult to read. Also, please fix the indentation. [How do I format posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: all your signout function does is navigate to the login page.  If you want some additional behavior, you need to add code for that

Comment: how would I fix proper hierarchy or should the login page not be a shellitem? sorry this is my first week mess around with maui and xaml

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?  From what I can tell its "when I navigate to Login it still shows the data from the previous login" or something like that.  Is that correct?

Comment: There's not one right way to do it. Personally, I would set the App's `MainPage` to a dedicated `LoginPage` instance and only set the `AppShell` as the App's `MainPage` after a successful login. The `LoginPage` wouldn't be a part of the Shell hierarchy in that scenario. Alternatively, you could define your `TabletLogin` as a singleton using Shell's dependency injection. You should then also register the ViewModel for the `TabletLogin` as a singleton as well. That way, the Page and ViewModel get instantiated each time the `TabletLogin` Page is opened.

Comment: @ewerspej Singleton means "one instance", not "single use". Adding pages or view models as singletons, if anything, will ensure that no second instance is ever created when the service is requested. Maybe you want to say AddTransient. AddTransient will have this effect for pages, that are manually registered in the Routing, without being registered as Shell Items. However, this will limit the use of absolute routing.

Comment: @H.A.H. You're absolutely right, I meant to write `AddTransient()`. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

This is intended. Pages are being reused.

Think for a second, what are the downsides if you are constructing new page after each navigation. Each page is another object in the memory. Obviously it will take time for some code to run.

And it is not just the page itself, the supporting classes that this page depends on will have to be reconstructed as well.

And what happens to the old page? All those resources should be safely disposed. (Not a trivial task, in many cases)

What is your goal after all?

> the page does not recreate and has the data from the first login still

So, clear this data. You are trying to buy new car, just because the light bulb has to be replaced.

Appearing or NavigatedTo events should be helpful, depending on your case. EventToCommandBehavior from the CommunityToolkit will help you do it.

Answer (score -1):

So after trying a few different things, I decided to create 3 app shells. one to handle the login of the app, one to handle phone views and one to handle tablet or desktop views as they will have more real estates. My starting shell is the login shell, if the user is logged they are sent to phone or tablet shell depending on the device and when the user logs out they are returned to the login shell.

**App.xaml.cs**
sending the user to login shell

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        MainPage = new AppShell_Login();

    }
}
```

**Login Method**

```
 async Task Login()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username)) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username)))
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                Validusername = false;

                return;
            }
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password)))

            {
                IsBusy = false;
                Validpassword = false;
                return;
            }
            UserLoginDto userInfo = new();
            userInfo.Username = Username; userInfo.Password = Password;
            try
            {
                  IsBusy = true;
                LoginResponse response = await apiService.Login(userInfo);
                if (response.Success)
                {


                    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Desktop)
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell_Tablet();

                    else if (DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell_Phone();
                    else if (DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet)
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell_Tablet();
                    else
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell_Phone();

                    IsBusy = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsBusy = false;
                    Failmessage = response.Message.ToString();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                Failmessage = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

**Signout Method**
returning user to login shell and clearing Preferences

```
private  void SignOut_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Preferences.Clear("refresh-token");
        Preferences.Clear("refresh-token-expires");
        Preferences.Clear("token");
        Preferences.Clear("userid");
        Preferences.Clear("username");
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell_Login();
        
    }
```